# How can I keep track of the changed checkboxes if I created those checkboxes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

inside a loop I'm creating multiple checkboxes using

```
checkbox = document.createElement("input");
```

I tried adding this inside the loop but it doesn't help

```
checkbox.setAttribute("onchange", function toggle() {});
```

I need some type of listener outside the loop to check which checkbox was changed so I can change the value inside localStorage of a boolean variable.

```
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox");
    
checkboxes[0].addEventListener("change", function toggle() {
  lists[checkboxes[0].value].tasks[checkboxes[0].id].completed = this.checked;
  localStorage.setItem("lists", JSON.stringify(lists));
});
```

I want something like this without having to give the checkboxes array a static index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the event listener inside the loop where you're creating them and access the clicked checkbox using `this` keyword or `event.target`:

```
checkbox.addEventListener("change", function toggle(event) {
  // this = checkbox.
  lists[this.value]?.tasks[this.id]?.completed = this.checked;
  localStorage.setItem("lists", JSON.stringify(lists));
});
```

You can use it's `id`, or a `data-*` attribute as the key of your `lists` like

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. I assumed that `checkbox.setAttribute("onchange", function toggle() {});` works the same as `checkbox.addEventListener("change", function toggle(event) {})` so I didnt try it inside the loop.